# Double enchantment glitch in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently noted that usually when I enchant in my enchantment table it gives me 2-3 free enchantments along with the actual one. For example, I enchanted a book to loyalty III and got sweeping edge II and power IV along with it. Also I enchanted my bow to infinity and got flame for free.

Is this normal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The chance to get extra enchantments increases when enchanting at a higher level (more bookshelves in the enchanting setup, picking the three pieces of lapis instead of one). The tooltips always display only the first possible enchantment.

More details on the relevant [wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting/Mechanics#Step_three_.E2.80.93_Select_a_set_of_enchantments_from_the_list).